# Regular Expression to find sequences of lowercase letters joined with underscore

Tags: regex

I can't seem to make my regular expression work.

I'd like to have some alpha text, no numbers, an underscore and then some more aplha text.

for example: blah_blah

I have an non-working example here

```
^[a-z][_][a-z]$
```

Thanks in advance people.

EDIT: I apologize, I'd like to enforce the use of all lower case.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$
```

Answer (score 3):

You just need:

`[a-z]+_[a-z]+`

or if it needs to be an entire line:

`^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+
```

Lowercase :

```
 [a-z]+_[a-z]+
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
^[a-z]+_[a-z]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which flavor of regex you're using there are a different possibilities:

```
^[A-Za-z]+_[A-Za-z]+$
^\a+_\a+$
^[[:alpha:]]+_[[:alpha:]]+$
```

The first form being the most widely accepted.

Your example suggests you're looking for things exactly like "blah_foo" and don't want to extract it from strings like "Hey blah_foo you". If this is not the case, you should drop the "^" (match the beginning of the string) and "$" (match the end of the string)